# Is $R= A[T] / (T^3-a)$ where $A$ is a left artinian ring and $a \in A$, left noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Is $R= A[T] / (T^3-a)$ where $A$ is a left artinian ring and $a \in A$, left noetherian?

I know $A[T]$ does NOT have to be a left artinian ring.

Any hints?

Maybe I can use the theorem if $N$ (submodule of $M$) and $M/N$ are artinian then so is $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

By the [Hopkins-Levitzki Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem), if $A$ is left Artinian, then it is left Noetherian.  Next, by [Hilbert's basis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem#Proof), $A[T]$ is left Noetherian.  Finally, any quotient of a left Noetherian ring is left Noetherian.